# "Attempt to present while already presenting" still appearing after checks?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uikit

```
 let appDelegate = UIKit.UIApplication.shared.delegate!

        if let tabBarController = appDelegate.window??.rootViewController as? UITabBarController {
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let signInVC   = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SignInVC") as! SignInVC

            guard !signInVC.isBeingPresented else {
                log.warning("Attempt to present sign in sheet when it is already showing")
                return
            }

            signInVC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.formSheet

            tabBarController.present(signInVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
```

This code can be called multiple times despite `signInVC` being presented. I already added this check:

```
 guard !signInVC.isBeingPresented else {
     log.warning("Attempt to present sign in sheet when it is already showing")
     return
 }
```

but it doesn't seem to prevent this error:

```
Warning: Attempt to present <App.SignInVC: 0x101f2f280>  on <UITabBarController: 0x101e05880> which is already presenting <App.SignInVC: 0x101f4e4c0>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `guard` isn't a valid check. The `isBeingPresented` is being called on a brand new view controller instance that hasn't yet been presented. So `isBeingPresented` will always be `false`. Besides that, that property can only be used from within a view controller's `view[Will|Did]Appear` method.

What you want to check is to see if the `tabBarController` has already presented another view controller or not.

And lastly, only create and setup the sign-in view controller if it should be presented.

```
let appDelegate = UIKit.UIApplication.shared.delegate!

if let tabBarController = appDelegate.window?.rootViewController as? UITabBarController {
    if tabBarController.presentedViewController == nil {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let signInVC   = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SignInVC") as! SignInVC
        signInVC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.formSheet

        tabBarController.present(signInVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Did this solve your issue or are you still having problems?